# Integer division without changing data type

Tags: c, integer, division

I am working division without changing data type.

```
int var1 = 7;   
int var2 = 2.0;  
float var = var1 / var2;    

printf("%f", var);
```

for the first 2 line, var1 and var2 data types cannot be changed. and line 3 is unchangeable. Is there a way to find the answer as 3.5

Comment: No, it's not possible. You need to cast one of the values to float.

Comment: You would have to use fixed point arithmetic. `int var = 1000*var1 / var2; printf("%d.%d", var/1000, var%1000);`